# WebAssemblyUriHelper missing in Blazor Preview 9

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

I have been using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Services.WebAssemblyUriHelper to get the base URI in my app

With the upgrade to Preview 9 the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Services appears to have been removed

What is the best way with preview 9 to get the base Uri?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your components you should use

```
@inject NavigationManager navigationManager
```

where do you previously using `IUrlNavigationManager`. Not sure why do you need to use `WebAssemblyUriHelper` directly.

Where you previously has call to method `uriHelper.GetBaseUrl()` you right now has property invocation `navigationManager.BaseUrl`.

Answer (score 1):

The team always write down the changes from previous version
see here what has changed

[ASP.NET Core and Blazor updates in .NET Core 3.0 Preview 9](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-and-blazor-updates-in-net-core-3-0-preview-9/)

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep an eye on that